# Entity framework migration Permission denied Mac

Tags: c#, macos, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I can't use any command of EF. Though .Net command work fine and they are installed globally. Here is a message I receive for all EF commands:

```
    System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): An error occurred trying to start process '/Users/xaxage/RiderProjects/swoove-orsy/Swoove.Orsy/Swoove.Orsy.Api/dotnet' with working directory '/Users/xaxage/RiderProjects/swoove-orsy/Swoove.Orsy/Swoove.Orsy.Api'. Permission denied
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Exe.Run(String executable, IReadOnlyList`1 args, String workingDirectory, Boolean interceptOutput)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Project.FromFile(String file, String buildExtensionsDir, String framework, String configuration, String runtime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Execute(String[] _)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
An error occurred trying to start process '/Users/xaxage/RiderProjects/swoove-orsy/Swoove.Orsy/Swoove.Orsy.Api/dotnet' with working directory '/Users/xaxage/RiderProjects/swoove-orsy/Swoove.Orsy/Swoove.Orsy.Api'. Permission denied
```

Yesterday when I added my first migration it worked. I am using Macbook M1 pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved my issue. I don't know why but inside my project was 'dotnet' file. After removing it everything works fine!

Here is the source I got the solution from:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21407